# recode column values using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am having trouble (likely because I am new to dplyr) trying to recode values. I am trying to split participants up by number, then recode the day value as 1 and so on. Currently it is day of the month.... my goal is to make it day of experiment. Note: The first date listed for a participant should be day 1 for them.

My attempt:

```
df<-data.frame(participant_number=c(1,1,1,2,2),month=c(3,3,4,3,3),day=c(6,6,1,7,8))
res<-setDT(df) %>% group_by(participant_number) %>% day
```

My goal:

```
participant_number day   month  recoded_day
1                  6       3     1
1                  6       3     1
1                  1       4     2
2                  7       3     1
2                  8       3     2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(participant_number) %>%
       mutate(recoded_day = day - day[1] + 1) 

Source: local data frame [5 x 3]
Groups: participant_number [2]

  participant_number   day recoded_day
               (dbl) (dbl)       (dbl)
1                  1     6           1
2                  1     6           1
3                  1     7           2
4                  2     7           1
5                  2     8           2
```

EDIT: If you have months and days, first make it into a date format (NB you need a year, especially if leap years are involved):

```
df$date <- as.Date(paste(df$month, df$day, "2015"), format = "%m %d %Y")
```

Then use the same code on this new date column:

```
df %>% group_by(participant_number) %>%
       mutate(recoded_day = as.numeric(date - date[1] + 1)) 

Source: local data frame [5 x 5]
Groups: participant_number [2]

  participant_number month   day       date recoded_day
               (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)     (date)       (dbl)
1                  1     3     6 2015-03-06           1
2                  1     3     6 2015-03-06           1
3                  1     4     1 2015-04-01          27
4                  2     3     7 2015-03-07           1
5                  2     3     8 2015-03-08           2
```

Comment: This works great, but doesn't take into account the month (if the first value is in June, July 1 returns negative value instead of a new day). My apologies, I have updated my code to reflect this edge case..... I hadn't considered it in my simple example. Can you update your solution?

Comment: @Rilcon42 It's confusing to see different data in the question and answer. In particular your question's "goal" seems to be wrong and the first part of this question seems to be using the wrong/old data. If you know the appropriate edit on the answer, you could go ahead and make the fixes in both places.

Comment: @Frank, What do you mean? The updated answer and the original question have matching data. Or did I miss something?

Comment: @Rilcon42 I tried to run through the Q&A and it didn't work because (1) your "goal" says 2 where jeremy's answer has 27 and (2) your "day" runs 6 6 1 7 8, while jeremy's is 6 6 7 7 8 (at least in the first part of his answer). It's generally bad form to significantly change the parameters of a question, but if you do it anyways, it's nice to update the answers so they don't look wrong.

Comment: I just tried to update his answer, but couldnt because the edit was only 2 characters. All that needs to happen is changing the 27 in column recoded_day to a 2

Answer (score 5):

I see `setDT()` in your code, so here's a complete *data.table* solution in case you are interested.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, 
    recoded_day := cumsum(c(1, diff(as.IDate(paste(month, day), "%m %d")))), 
    by = participant_number
]
```

which gives us

```
   participant_number month day recode_day
1:                  1     3   6          1
2:                  1     3   6          1
3:                  1     4   1         27
4:                  2     3   7          1
5:                  2     3   8          2
```